# Saving form values for a list of objects within another object in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I have

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<ClassB> ClassBList { get; set; }
}


public class ClassB
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}

// View Model Razor is using
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public List<ClassA> ClassAList { get; set }

    public IndexViewModel()
    {
        ClassAList = /*...init list from repository method...*/
    }
}

// POST method
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(IndexViewModel model)
{
   // Here is where only the model has the updated ClassA properties, but not their ClassB properties

   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

In my ViewModel I have a List of ClassA. In my view, I want the put the list of ClassA's in a form as well as their containing ClassB's so that both the ClassA and ClassB objects can be updated.

So in my view I have

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ClassA.Count(); i++)
{
    <input asp-for="@Model.ClassA[i].ID" />

    @for (int j = 0; j < Model.ClassA[i].ClassBList.Count(); j++)
    {
       <input asp-for="@Model.ClassA[i].ClassBList[j].ID" />
       <input asp-for="@Model.ClassA[i].ClassBList[j].Name" />
       <input asp-for="@Model.ClassA[i].ClassBList[j].IsValid" />
    }
}
```

And here is the view model

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public List<ClassA> ClassAList { get; set }
}
```

When the form submits, in the post method, the ClassA properties get updated, however, none of the ClassB properties for that ClassA object do.

Is there a way to engage the properties in ClassBList as well as its parent ClassA properties?

Comment: What type is the incoming model on Controllers action? What type are you using on View?

Comment: Maybe you should start simple, with a plain model without nested properties. Because your form binding is already incorrect which suggests that you haven’t solved the simple case yet.

Comment: @OctoCode So the View is using the same model as what the form submits to the controller. In this case, Razor is using "@model ViewModels.Home.IndexViewModel" and the controller is also using the IndexViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an error, which can result in either Exception or Binding data override.

Change:

```
i < Model.ClassA[i].ClassBList.Count()
```

To:

```
j < Model.ClassA[i].ClassBList.Count()
```

Also make sure, your model is a class and not a list.

```
@model SomeViewModel and not @model List<ClassA>
```

Comment: There are so many assumptions where OP is wrong. This is the partial answer at best.

Comment: @StephenMuecke It can be and more wise to be `model SomeModelContainingAPropertyOfListClassACalledClassA`

Comment: It can be bu it does not need to be. And OP has not shown the view model they are using :)

Comment: Sorry that was actually just a typo in the OP. I just simplified the classes that I'm actually using in my app for readability. I do have it correct in my code. I've update the OP to include my view model and controller action @OrelEraki

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've update the OP to include my view model and controller action. Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: @Daath, The code you have shown (with the correction noted above) works just fine. But I'm assuming that is not your real code.